# Print in italic through XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm philologist and I just started to know this kind of syntax. I would like to recover `name proper` but under condition that whatever is in `ex` is printed in italics, how could I put it in the first column of this table?

This is the XML:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="1.antroponimoscopia.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Title</title>
            </titleStmt>
            <publicationStmt>
                <p>Publication Information</p>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <p>Information about the source</p>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text>
        <body>
            <pb n="001r"/>
            <div1 type="book" n="01">
                
                <div2 type="chapter" n="000">
                    <cb n="a"/>
                    <head> Capítulo 1 </head>
                    <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 1 de la columna A del folio 1r y le pongo dos
                        nombrecitos <name type="proper">Don alfo<ex>ns</ex>so</name> y otro nombrecillo para no perdernos doña
                        <name type="proper">beatriz</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
                <div2 type="chapter" n="001">
                    <cb n="b"/>
                    <head>Capítulo II </head>
                    
                    <ab>Este es el texto del capítulo II, que se encuentra en la columba B del folio 1r.
                        Y vamos a poner unos nombres: don <name type="proper">al<ex>fon</ex>so</name>, doña <name type="proper">Urraca</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
                <pb n="001v"/>
                <div2 type="chapter" n="002">
                    <head>Capítulo III</head>
                    <ab> Este es el texto del capítulo 3. Vamos a poner tres nombres:
                        <name type="proper">Fer<ex>nan</ex>do</name>, <name type="proper">Le<ex>tic</ex>ia</name> e <name type="proper">I<ex>s</ex>a</name>
                    </ab>
                </div2>
            </div1>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="es">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h3 align="center">
                    <b>Antropónimos</b>
                </h3>
                <table width="750" border="1" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Nombre</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Libro</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Capítulo</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Folio</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Columna</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                            <div align="center">Línea</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tei:div1/@n"/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tei:div2/@n"/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding::tei:pb[@n][1]/@n"/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding::tei:cb[@n][1]/@n"/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding::tei:lb[@n][1]/@n"/>
                                </div>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would suggest to set up templates for the nodes you want to transform and for the `name type="proper"` elements you would use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:name[@type = 'proper']">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

and for its `ex` children e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:name[@type = 'proper']/tei:ex">
  <em>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </em>
</xsl:template>
```

Keep in mind that XSLT is just a programming language used to transform XML to other formats, so it is not XSLT that determines any italic or other rendering, it is just used to produce the output you want, in your case it seems to be HTML, where the `em` element is supposed to give emphasis. You could also choose to use CSS instead. But if you want to transform to PDF you would need to use XSLT to generate the right XSL-FO element and the needed attributes.

A more complete example would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" doctype-system="about:legacy-comapat"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="es">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h3 align="center">
                    <b>Antropónimos</b>
                </h3>
                <table width="750" border="1" align="center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Nombre</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Libro</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Capítulo</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Folio</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Columna</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" bgcolor="#00CCFF">
                                <div align="center">Línea</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>                        
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:name[@type = 'proper']"/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:name[@type = 'proper']">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tei:div1/@n"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tei:div2/@n"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:name[@type = 'proper']/tei:ex">
        <em>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </em>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5Et

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's is certainly very complet. I'm sorry for bothering you again. I'm trying, but I don't know exactly where I have to add, in the table, what you've sent me... Sorry  @MartinHonnen

Comment: The whole task is not clear to me as you seem to have several columns, yet in each you use the same `<xsl:for-each select="//tei:name[@type='proper']">`. I reduced my answer on the simple way to transform the `tei:ex` to an HTML element like `em`. The rest will fall into place if you use push based, template match processing for the whole stylesheet. See the edit.